# Lyx 2.1 Cannot Insert Anything

Tags: lyx

I am trying to continue writing a document I started a few months ago. When I tried inserting equations into the document the option was greyed out. I just updated to the newest version of lyx 2.1.5dev(July 2015) and also cleared out ~/.lyx2.1 but the problem remains exactly the same. Basically, every single option in the insert menu is greyed out.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Hi Tony. How can we replicate your current setup? That is paramount in order to address your concerns adequately.

Comment: @Werner , I guess to replicate the setup you would need all my settings. I just cleared /usr/share/lyx2.1 and reinstalled, but I found out that reinstalling did not recreate /usr/share/lyx2.1. I think the problem was that it was using old settings which did not correctly carry over after some update. But now, I am unable to open lyx at all because it says it cannot find some file it was expecting in /usr/share/lyx2.1. Are you aware of any way to regenerate these files? Should they be created automatically during installation?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with setting up software on Linux and/or Mac.

Comment: I cleared everything lyx related on my computer except for documents, `sudo apt-get remove lyx lyx2.1` `sudo rm -rf \`find / -iname "lyx*"`\` then reinstalled and when I open a new document I still cannot insert any equations.

Comment: @TonyRuth I think my answer is the correct one. Do you have any feedback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I would have put this answer in a comment first but I do not have enough “reputation points”.)

What is your Ubuntu version? My guess is the bug described here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-appmenu/+bug/1430059. In particular see the workaround at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-appmenu/+bug/1430059/comments/20:

> The proper workaround is to run lyx with the command line: `QT_X11_NO_NATIVE_MENUBAR=1 lyx` or equivalently to adapt `/usr/share/applications/lyx.desktop` as follows: `Exec=env QT_X11_NO_NATIVE_MENUBAR=1 lyx %F`

But the bug should be fixed now in Ubuntu, and therefore upgrading the distribution might help.

Notice that this has been cross-posted at http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/9905. When you cross-post a bug report, please indicate it and provide a link.